# R: Replace values in dataframe A with dataframe B based on criteria

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, find

I've made a few stabs at this within R but haven't found a workable / elegant solution.

I am trying to replace values in df_1

```
df_1

  Year   Event          Loss   Control
1    5 2000003      78652058       180
2    5 2000013     130063819       251
3    7 2000023     299725787       266
4    8 2000033    2916285664       160
5    6 2000333    3254545464       162
```

with appropriate values in df_2

```
df_2

  Year   Event_1       Loss1   Event_2   Loss2
1    5   2000003  35318435.6   2000013  323380
3    7   2000023   7152099.6         0       0
4    8   2000033    985406.7         0       0
```

I need to match 'Event_1' within df_2 to 'Event' within df_1 by 'Year' and replace 'Loss' within df_1 with 'Loss1' from df_2. The same also needs to be done for 'Event_2' and 'Loss2'. 'Event_1' and 'Event_2' within each 'Year' of df_2 will always be unique and will always be contained within df_1. If 'Event_1' or 'Event_2' is 0, no replacements should happen. There will be instances of 'Year' and 'Event' within df_1 not contained in df_2.

**Update**

The output should be the below:

```
  Year   Event          Loss   Control
1    5 2000003    35318435.6       180
2    5 2000013        323380       251
3    7 2000023     7152099.6       266
4    8 2000033      985406.7       160
5    6 2000333    3254545464       162
```

'Loss' in row 1 of df_1 is replaced with 'Loss1' from row 1 of df_2 as df_1$Event[1] = df_2$Event_1[1] AND df_1$Year[1] = df_2$Year[1]. df_1$Loss[2] is replaced with df_2$Loss2[1] as df_1$Event[2] = df_2$Event2[1] AND df_1$Year[2] = df_1$Year[1]. df_2$Year will be unique in every row. df_2$Event_1 and df_2$Event_2 within a row will never be the same value.

Comment: Could you please add your expected output for the sample data?

Comment: There are two Year=5 entries in df1 so it's ambiguous to request replacement into df1 based on year. I suppose one might guess that the replacements should be in sequence, but we've not been guaranteed that the number of items in a single year df2 row will not exceed the number of rows in df1 within a year. Looks like the right approach might be to reshape df2 to long format with Year and Event as a joint "time" variable and then match on Year and event jointly.

Comment: what should be your output?

Answer (score 0):

I think this gets you what you want

```
within(df_1, {
  df2_loss1 <- df_2$Loss1[match(interaction(Event, Year), with(df_2, interaction(Event_1, Year)))]
  df2_loss2 <- df_2$Loss2[match(interaction(Event, Year), with(df_2, interaction(Event_2, Year)))]
  Loss <- case_when(
    !is.na(df2_loss1) & !df2_loss1 == 0 ~ as.numeric(df2_loss1),
    !is.na(df2_loss2) & !df2_loss2 == 0 ~ as.numeric(df2_loss2),
    TRUE ~ Loss
  )
  # rm(df2_loss1, df2_loss2)
})
```

Note that the example does not contain 0s, so this is not tested.